# Translation of "grammar Nazi"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase

The English term ["grammar Nazi"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grammar_Nazi) is often used to describe a person who is overly pedantic about grammar. From what I have experienced in the English speaking world, it is [generally considered acceptable](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21935/is-grammar-nazi-politically-correct) in an informal context, and does not carry any significant overtones of the historic party or its atrocities.

However, Germans seem to be much more sensitive about this issue, and have even banned most depictions of Nazi symbols, for good reason.

Therefore, I was wondering if there was any equally idiomatic translation of the phrase into German, and if the literal translation "Grammatiknazi" is a reasonable usage in colloquial German.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The word 'Nazi' has a way stronger meaning in German than in English. I was surprised how it's easily used in North America. It seems to stem from the *Seinfeld* show where there is a *Soup Nazi* which was already related to in an earlier comment.

Never ever use the word 'Nazi' in German, ever! The only exception would be to name a person who's following the views and opinions of the former NSDAP. The 'believers' of White Supremacy are often called *Neonazis* by German news papers.

I met *non smoking nazis*, *laundry nazis*, *whatever nazis*. The informal use has soften the meaning of the word. That did not happen in the German language nor in Germany as such.

Comment: I would disagree. It's true that for many Germans *Nazi* has a very strong meaning, but it can depend on context. From the many up and down votes on my answer below I can see how controversial this topic is. But I definitely wouldn't say that the word Nazi in softened context is an absolute no-go. It's definitely less common than in English and a lot more controversial but definitely not something you wouldn't hear now and then. I would say that context matters and a *laundry nazi* doesn't make a real Nazi any more acceptable.

Comment: @JanekBevendorff Was there ever a situation in a German speaking environment when somebody was called a Nazi outside of a political context? I'd be glad to learn what this was.

Comment: Sure. It pretty much only exists in spoken language and it's not very common, but I've definitely heard it a couple of times. And not from people who would trivialize violence, racism or hatred against foreigners.

Comment: I agree that the connotations of _nazi_ differ between German and English. As a (right-hand) part of a compound, however, it *can* be disconnected from any NSDAP association even in German. It’s still better to avoid, though.

Comment: @Chrissov: Du gehst offenbar von einer Intention des Sprechers oder Schreibers aus, konfliktträchtige Sprache zu vermeiden. Das ist unprofessionell. Du weißt nicht, ob der Sprecher oder Schreiber nicht gerade auf den Konflikt aus ist, und ob nicht gerade deshalb *Nazi* das Sprachmittel der Wahl ist. Bedenke, dass ein Autor oft nicht den Leser adressiert, sondern von einer Person berichtet, die einer dritten Person etwas sagt. Auch wenn Du so etwas nie schreiben würdest können andere Leute ein Interesse haben. Auch wenn Du dieses Interesse ablehnst kann es für diese der passende Ausdruck sein,

Answer (score 11):

Any literal translation of *grammar nazi* should be avoided in German. It’s actually encountered once in a while, as is the original English term, but I take that as proof that people who know the English expression don’t know an equivalent German one even if they’re proficient native speakers.

If it’s okay to lose (or loosen) some semantic associations, I would suggest ***Sprachfetischist*** or ***Sprachfaschist***, although both have just ca. 1000 Google hits at the time of writing.
Both compounds use the more generic *Sprache* ‘language’ instead of *Grammatik* ‘grammar’. 
They also both have the *+ist* ending common to extremism of all kinds. 
For the *Fetischist*, language is something they need or need to care about to feel good, i.e. something between a hobby and the only purpose in life. 
The *Faschist* has a totalitarian and absolutist view on language where only one way is right – their way (probably also found in The Book).

Answer (score 7):

A noun such as *Grammatik* in combination with the term *Nazi* to describe someone who is overly pedantic exists in German as well. But I would argue that it is not as common as in English which is probably also the reason why many Germans actually use the  English expression *Grammar Nazi* (or *Grammar-Nazi* which would be correct German orthography). But you will only find that in spoken language.

Another more common (but also very colloquial) term is *Korinthenkacker* which literally describes someone who poops raisins, but actually means someone who is annoyingly correct and pedantic in some way. This term, however, is a general expression for anyone who shows that kind of behavior, not just for grammar things. So it basically only means *nitpicker* which is also a general expression. You can't make the word more specific by composing it with other words. The expression *Grammatik-Korinthenkacker* does not exist or is at least extremely rare.

Comment: "Oberlehrer" is of similar connotation, especially in internet fora. But misses the grammar relationship as well. And, BTW,  no, I do not use "Nazi" to describe overly pedantic people.

Comment: Ich finde die Antwort gut, aber grammar nazi wörtlich zu übersetzen und sogar noch als Grammar-Nazi halb einzudeutschen, halte ich für völligen Murks.

Answer (score 4):

Grammatiknazi ist die beste Übersetzung, wenn man nahe am Original bleiben will.

Einerseits versteht man in Deutschland unter einem Nazi das gleiche wie in englischsprachigen Ländern, andererseits werden Metaphern und Übertreibungen hier nach den selben Regeln gebildet wie dort.

Die politische Erregbarkeit ist wohl bei diesem Thema etwas höher, so dass man hier vielleicht vorsichtiger ist, jemanden derart zu bezeichnen - es wäre ein peinlicher Faux Pas einen Überlebenden des Holocaust so zu benennen, einen Angehörigen oder ein Mitglied einer Opfergruppe.

Eine Beobachtung [in freier Natur](http://scienceblogs.de/astrodicticum-simplex/2016/04/20/wrint-wissenschaft-folge-48-tiroler-jodler-vs-piefke/) bestätigt mich darin, dass das Wort durchaus verwendet wird, allerdings ist der Autor Österreicher.

Soeben wurde auch auf 3sat in der Sendung "Shakespears letzte Runde" von einem Darsteller eine andere Person als XY-Nazi bezeichnet, wobei ich bei der Suche nach diesem Beitrag vergessen habe, was XY konkret war, jedenfalls war es eine an sich ähnlich unverfängliche Sache wie Grammatik.

Die vielen Downvotes bestätigen leider die Befürchtung, dass viele Deutsche glauben, man dürfte als Deutscher oder in Deutschland nicht den leisesten Anflug intellektueller Distanz zum Thema zeigen, sondern müsse in jedem Fall vorab eine unmissverständliche Distanzierung zeigen, selbst wenn man andere zitiert, selbst wenn man fiktive Gestalten 
 auf die Bühne bringt, die nun mal so reden wie im richtigen Leben oder eben auch ganz anders.

Die Sprache ist da agnostisch, und Menschen die diese ängstlichen Distanzierungsrituale verweigern oder vielleicht auch nicht kennen gibt es nun mal, und je länger die Vergangenheit her ist, desto mehr werden es.

Wer das als Aufforderung missverstehen will einen Schlussstrich zu ziehen, der hat es nicht verstanden. Wie gut Antifaschismus qua Dressur funktioniert kann man m.E. z.Zt. fast täglich in den Nachrichten lesen.

Comment: Verwendet wird es, aber mein Respekt für den Autor ist ziemlich nahe bei Null. Über "grammar nazi" kann ich lachen, aber jemanden Angesicht zu Angesicht "Grammatik-Nazi" zu nennen halte ich für ungesund.

Comment: It is good practice to answer questions in the language they have been asked.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest "[I-Tüpferl-Reiter](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/i_Tuepferl_Reiter)".

It is colloquial and more common in the southern part of the Germanosphere (particular Austria).

"i-Tüpferl reiten" can refer to all kinds of pedantic behaviour but originally it was complaining about missing dots on the "i"s in handwritten text.

Comment: +1, even though I've never heard this term in Germany.

Comment: Ein i-Tüpferl-Reiter ist ganz allgemein ein Pedant. Ein besonderer Bezug zur Sprache oder Grammatik besteht nicht. Der Ausdruck bezeichnet ursprünglich jemanden, der sich darüber aufregt (und dann auch ausführlich darauf herumreitet), dass ein anderer den Punkt auf einem kleinen i nicht gemacht hat. Daher wird das Wort »i-Tüpferl-Reiter«, obwohl es ein Substantiv ist, mit kleinem i am Beginn geschrieben. Ein i-Tüpferl-Reiter ist also jemand, der sich über unbedeutende kleine Fehler übermäßig aufregt. Wie gesagt: Ohne besonderen Bezug zur Sprache, also nicht sinnverwandt mit »grammar nazi«.

Answer (score 2):

Ich finde das Wort "Sprachpolizist" könnte alles sagen. Das Wort beschreibt eine Person die überwachet, dass alles Gesagte und Geschriebene korrekt und gesetzgemäss ausgedrückt wird. Zudem ist das Wort einfach und ziemlich eindeutig und ohne jede politische oder religiöse Belastung